# Ext TreePanel: How to add Child Nodes to the expanded node?

Tags: extjs4.2, extjs-stores

I am trying to create a Tree from Ext.tree.Panel with JSON data.

```
My JSON
{
"employees": [
{ "firstName":"John" , "lastName":"Doe" }, 
{ "firstName":"Anna" , "lastName":"Smith" }, 
{ "firstName":"Peter" , "lastName":"Jones" }
]
}
```

I want the first level nodes to be the "firstName: from the above JSON. I am able to achieve this but when any of the node is expanded the same nodes are displayed as children to the expanded node shown below.

```
- John
---> + John
---> + Anna
---> + Peter
+ Anna
+ Peter
```

When any of the node is expanded I want to add children from another JSON file. but here the problem is before adding the children to the node i can see the child nodes attached as above.

Is there any way to avoid this behavior ?

Code Snippet

```
My TreePanel:

Ext.define('MyApp.view.MyTreePanel', {
extend: 'Ext.tree.Panel',
height: 439,
width: 400,
title: 'My Tree Panel',
store: 'MyTreeStore',
displayField: 'firstName',
rootVisible: false,
initComponent: function() {
var me = this;
Ext.applyIf(me, {
viewConfig: {
}
});
me.callParent(arguments);
}
});


TreeStore:

Ext.define('MyApp.store.MyTreeStore', {
extend: 'Ext.data.TreeStore',
requires: [
'MyApp.model.MyModel'
],
constructor: function(cfg) {
var me = this;
cfg = cfg || {};
me.callParent([Ext.apply({
autoLoad: true,
autoSync: true,
model: 'MyApp.model.MyModel',
storeId: 'MyTreeStore',
proxy: {
type: 'ajax',
url: 'employees.json',
reader: {
type: 'json',
root: 'employees'
}
}
}, cfg)]);
}
});

**Model:**

Ext.define('MyApp.model.MyModel', {
extend: 'Ext.data.Model',
fields: [
{
name: 'firstName'
}
]
});
```

Thanks in advance....

Answer (score 0):

The url will get called for every node you click on that hasn't been 'loaded' yet.  I'm not sure why ExtJS does this as the parameters change per node clicked. What I've done because I needed a lot of extra functionality is override the load() in the tree.Store (sorry, it's a little messy and could use a cleanup):

```
Ext.define('MyApp.store.MyTreeStore', {
    extend: 'Ext.data.TreeStore',
    load: function(options) {
        options = options || {};
        options.params = options.params || {};

        var me = this,
            node = options.node || me.tree.getRootNode(),
            root;

        // If there is not a node it means the user hasnt 
        // defined a rootnode yet. In this case lets just
        // create one for them.
        if (!node) {
            node = me.setRootNode({
                expanded: true
            });
        }

        if (me.clearOnLoad) {
            node.removeAll();
        }

        Ext.applyIf(options, {
            node: node
        });

        options.params[me.nodeParam] = node ? node.getId() : 'root';

        if (node) {
            node.set('loading', true);
        }

        var root = me.getRootNode();

        if (node.isRoot()) {
            // put some root option.params here. 
            // otherwise, don't pass any if you don't need to
        } else  {
            options.params = Ext.JSON.encode({
                // or some parameter here for the node to 
                // get back the correct JSON data
                nodeId: node.get('id') 
            });
        }

        return me.callParent([options]);
    },
    model: 'MyApp.model.MyModel',
    storeId: 'MyTreeStore',
    proxy: {
        type: 'ajax',
        url: 'employees.json',
        reader: {
            type: 'json',
            root: 'employees'
        }
    },
    autoLoad: false,
    listeners: {
        append: function(store,node,index) {
            // on append depth 1 is first level, beforeappend it is 0  
            if (node.get('depth') == 1) {                    
                // setting these values here assures that the node knows it's been loaded already.
                // node.set('leaf',true); force leaf true, false or whatever you want. 
                node.set('loaded',true);
                node.commit();
            }
        }
    }
});
```

Also, you can do something like this to your JSON if you need to have the expand / collapse icons there.  These are default fields that get added by default.

```
{
    "employees": [
    { "firstName":"John" , "lastName":"Doe", leaf: false, children: []}, 
    { "firstName":"Anna" , "lastName":"Smith", leaf: false, children: []}, 
    { "firstName":"Peter" , "lastName":"Jones", leaf: false, children: []}
    ]
}
```